# MongoDB getDatabaseNames() deprecated

Tags: java, mongodb

I'm getting started with MongoDB in Java, and I'm trying to print my databases.
I'm using the following code and `.getDatabaseNames()` is deprecated, is there a better way to do this? Or it doesn't matter? It is working fine. Thanks in advance.

```
private static void printDatabases(MongoClient mongo) {
    List<String> dbs = mongo.getDatabaseNames();
    for (String db : dbs) {
        System.out.println(" - " + db);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for [listDatabases()](http://api.mongodb.com/java/current/com/mongodb/MongoClient.html#listDatabaseNames--)